# MOSFET switching losses in LTSpice

Tags: mosfet, ltspice, switching-losses

I've made a simulation of three-phase MOSFET rectifier in LTSpice. I am simulating different conduction angles and calculating efficiency. However, I would like to also take a look at the switching losses, particularly switching losses vs. conduction angle. I am not after high-accuracy data, I would just like to see if there is a difference. Can I do that in LTSpice and how? If not, is there a software that has MOSFET switching losses functionality built-in?

[LTSpice simulation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jcev1uqfy9b9fbl/sync%20rectifier%20efficiency%20step%20width.asc?dl=0)

Comment: You can probably plot the instantaneous power \$p(t)=i_D(t)\times v_{DS}(t)\$ and you will see the peaks showing the turn-on and off losses with the conduction loss in the middle. If you average \$p(t)\$ along a switching cycle, you'll get the average power. Not sure switching losses are relevant in simulation as many stray elements are involved that are not modeled. Usually the prototype is the only way to determine these losses. On the contrary, conduction losses are usually well simulated if you account for the junction temperature effect on \$r_{DS(on)}\$.

Comment: You will also want to pay attention to the power delivered by the gate drivers, which is not currently accounted for in your input power calculation.

Comment: If you hold `ALT` pressed and `R-Click` with the mouse over the MOS, it will plot the total instantaneous power dissipation. After that you can `CTRL+L-Click` the label of the waveform (in the waveform viewer) and it will display some useful calculations.